# How to solve piwik tracking origin issue

Tags: matomo

I get this when I call my application

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://tracker.ushahidi.com/piwik/piwik.php?idsite=36439&rec=1. Origin http://maps.zgb.de is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I don´t mind the application being tracked, it´s just that I don´t know why this is a problem.

any comments would be welcome,

yours,

Rob

Answer (score 1):

What happens is the domain where Piwik is installed is not the same as where the app is.

valipour has a pretty good explanation about this here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11281976/421042