# jQuery ajax and getJSON requests hitting access-control-allow-origin issues

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm attempting to grab a file from a different server using jquery's `$.ajax` or `$.getJSON`, but I'm hitting the `access-control-allow-origin` wall, and the jsonp options don't seem to work for me.

The site is using jQuery 1.5.1.

Here are my three tests:

Using basic $.ajax, the url requested never has `?callback=?` appended:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    datatype: 'jsonp',
    error: function(){console.log('error');},
    success: function(){console.log('success');}
});
```

Using basic $.ajax with an attempted hack, still get cross-site issues:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url + '.jsonp?callback=?',
    datatype: 'jsonp',
    error: function(){console.log('error');},
    success: function(){console.log('success');}
});
```

Using $.getJSON, beats the cross site issues, but the error case is never triggered:

```
$.getJSON(url + '?callback=?',
    function(data){
        console.log('success');
    })
    .error(function(){
        console.log('error');
    })
    .success(function(){
        console.log('success!');
    });
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong? In the end, I'm trying to test to see if the url exists, and do something on error if it doesn't.

**Edit**: The url I'm attempting to access does not exist. I'm expecting the error case to be triggered.

Answer (score 3):

In order to be able to access an external resource from javascript. The remote resource MUST include `access-control-allow-origin` in the response header. If you have control over that resource, you need to add this response header to `*` (or your domain if you want a more restricted access control).

Read more about this here: http://enable-cors.org/

If you do not control that external resource. Solutions are more tricky. Some people take use of YUI to do cross-domain ajax calls. See here: http://jpvalappil.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/cross-domain-ajax-the-yui-way/.

If you are writing a chrome-extension, the API allows you to grant permissions to your extension to access resources of other domains from js.

Comment: I'm waiting for the backend dev to come online, but this endpoint works if the file exists (usually, despite my current issues), so I'm assuming this is in place? I'll check when he's back.

Comment: Also, the third case isn't hitting the access-control-allow-origin issue. Any thoughts on why the error function isn't being triggered?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery-JSONP](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp). This script allows you to catch errors (although without any meaningful error message).

```
   $.jsonp({
      "url": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/"+userId+"?callback=?",
      "data": {
          "alt": "json-in-script"
      },
      "success": function(userProfile) {
          // handle user profile here 
      },
      "error": function(d,msg) {
          alert("Could not find user "+userId);
      }
    });
```

Is is supported by major browsers:

- Internet Explorer 6+
- Firefox 2+
- Chrome 1+
- Safari 3+
- Opera 9+

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify a **timeout**:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url : url,
    timeout : 1000
})
    .done(function(data) {logdata(data); })
    .fail(function() { logdata("error"); });
```

Comment: Tried that just to check, but the issue isn't a timeout, it's `access-control-allow-origin`

Answer (score 0):

you used datatype but you should use dataType.

Comment: Untrue. `datatype` and `dataType` give the exact same results in AJAX.

Comment: well changing it to dataType fixed it for me